# elementary Loki 0.4 (64bit), Dual boot: delete one OS and join partition with elementary?

Tags: dual-boot

i have dual (linux) boot; elementary (loki) and Mint (sarah)
each partition is roughly 100GB.

how do i delete Mint, and join both partitions?

Thank you
Pine Sol

Answer (score 1):

Each partition is containing the whole system? Which one is handling GRUB-boot manager?
Do you have an extra Data-Partition?

If eOS is handling Grub you could just boot up any Live-Image, start GParted or Gnome Disks, delete Mint and increase the size of Loki's partition.

Be sure to make backups before, as data loss can happen when changing partitions.